# java.util.Set adds duplicate entries

Tags: java

The below is my code,

```
public class Myclass{
     some code is here.
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
     Set<Myclass> set = new HashSet<Myclass>();
     Myclass mc = new Myclass();
     for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
       set.add(mc);
     }
     System.out.println("size of set : "+set.size());
   }
```

The above code is print the output 2 but it will be 1. Is there any wrong with my code, if so then please suggest me how to avoid adding duplicate entries in set. I have override the equals() in my Myclass class.

Please reply me as soon as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you reimplemented `equals` and `hashCode`?

Comment: "some code" matters, especially if it's one of the methods used by `Set<>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You presumably need to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` for `MyClass`, otherwise it won't properly check equality.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. I have already implement equals() in my MyClass then also it will adds duplicate entries.

Comment: Can you show your equals() and hashCode() methods? maybe you implement them wrong

Comment: @Lokesh: Did you miss the "and"?

Comment: @Lokesh: you need to implement both `equals()` AND `hashCode()`. Please post your code for those methods.

Comment: hi, i m not sure that my equals method works properly b'coz, when I m debugging my code the break point is not come in equals().

Comment: ok thank for reply I will try to implement hashCode() in my Myclass class.

Comment: Hi, I have override both equals() and hashCode() method but it will not work.

Comment: hi thanks for reply my hashCode() implementation was wrong. Now it is working properly. thanks once again.